# Placing default value

Tags: javascript, reactjs, input

I stuck with a problem and hope someone can help me.
I build the calculation app using user input. All fields are not mandatory. I use

```
   const [salesIncrease, setSalesIncrease] = useState(0);
   const [priceIncrease, setPriceIncrease] = useState(0);
   const [costsDecrease, setCostsDecrease] = useState(0);

 function handleSalesIncreaseChange(e) {
  setSalesIncrease(parseInt(e.target.value, 10));
 }
function handlePriceIncreaseChange(e) {
 setPriceIncrease(parseInt(e.target.value, 10));
}
function handleCostsDecreaseChange(e) {
 setCostsDecrease(parseInt(e.target.value, 10));
}
```

I pass it as props to

```
    <Optimisation 
      salesIncrease={salesIncrease}
      priceIncrease={priceIncrease}
      costsDecrease={costsDecrease}
      onSalesIncrease={handleSalesIncreaseChange}
      onPriceIncrease={handlePriceIncreaseChange}
      onCostsDecrease={handleCostsDecreaseChange}/
```

and pass it to input field like this:

```
<Input
      className="salesInc"
      value={props.salesIncrease}
      onChange={props.onSalesIncrease}
    />
```

This values I use in calculations and present a table and graphs with results.
The problem. At first, as fields are not mandatory, I can fill any of them and it works perfectly. default useState = 0. The thing is, if user add the number and after delete the number, all the calculations where this field involved give NaN. So by deleting input, he set automatically value to NaN. If user type there 0 or any other number it works again, but if he uses that field once, he cannot live it empty.
Question: How can I set value for input min 0 do not break the calculations and do not force user set 0 in the input field if he used it once?

I tried this function:

```
 function handleVolumeInput(salesIncrease) {
  if (isNaN(salesIncrease)) {
  return 0;
 }
 return salesIncrease;}
```

}

and pass this function to props value:

```
  onSalesInput={handleVolumeInput}

  <Input
      className="salesInc"
      value={props.onSalesInput()}
      onChange={props.onSalesIncrease}
      
    />
```

but this doesn't work. I still get NaN when delete once set data from input. Any other solution please?

Comment: Have you tried returning `salesIncrease || 0`?

Comment: and how do you use it? when I try  function handleVolumeInput(salesIncrease) {
    this.salesIncrease = salesIncrease || 0;
  } I get an error "Cannot assign to read only property 'salesIncrease' of object '#<Object>'

Answer (score 0):

You can use numeric type input like this:

```js
<input type="number" name="age" id="age" min="1" max="10" step="2">
```

You can read more about it at - https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Learn/Forms/HTML5_input_types#numeric_field

Comment: I use Chakra UI. I have minimum there  <NumberInput min={0} ml="auto" mb={2}>. <NumberInputField
          className={classes}
          type="number" > Unfortunately it doesn't help.

Comment: I think the problem is, that all initial values are overbid by useState setVolume, which always pass the update, even if the is NaN. May be an idea how I can I ALWAYS return initial value 0 if case if there is NaN? I tried, but as I said my version didn't help